# CoreData the save method is not working

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Im a creating an app for my iPhone using coredata.

I have a viewcontroller with an object i want to save that object to my FavoriteViewController.
By clicking a button favorite I want my object to be save into the managedObjectContext but I'm getting the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to perform another operation with a fetch already in progress'. ***

My Code:

```
// Step 1: Create Object
Favorite * newFavorite = (Favorite*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Favorite" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

// Step 2: Set Properties       
    newFavorite.name = @"Company";

    NSLog(@"%@",newFavorite);

// Step 3: Save Object

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![newFavorite.managedObjectContext save:&error]) { // this is where the program crash
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads in your application?

Comment: No im not using multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess you have a UI element, such as a table, that activates a fetch when the UI is changed. For example, if you have a fetched results controller, any scrolling of the table can activate the fetched results controller's fetch.

You can't mutate a collection while iterating over that collection because the count of the iteration changes while the iteration is in process. A fetch iterates over the collection of objects matching its entity and predicate. If you insert an object while the fetch is working you will get an error.

Usually you see this problem with multiple threads but I think the UI might trigger the problem in the right set of circumstances.

Comment: Yes I do have tableview that fetch the data. I want to save or copy over that data to another manageObjectContext. How can I do that without fetching the data?

Comment: You must be doing something unusual to trigger to the table update at the same time as the fetch. Is the UI element that triggers the insertion of the new object itself embedded in the tableview? If you have two or more context, their individual changes may be colliding with one another. I can't say without knowing more about your app.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably changed something in your tables. If this is true, try to use the original values for the table `Z_METADATA (Z_VERSION, Z_UUID, Z_PLIST), Z_PRIMARYKEY (Z_ENT)`...